# ConfigFactory not found

Tags: magento-2.1, installation

I just installed Magento 2.1.14 (fresh install) and the admin backend works fine, but the storefront gives an error, when looking into the error report, I get the following error message:

> Class Magento\Persistent\Model\Persistent\ConfigFactory does not exist

I tried looking this up, but found no real solution. Also the installation tutorial gives no help.

Comment: Can you delete the generated/code, generated/meta and var/cache, var/view_processed, var/page_cache and run the setup upgrade, di compile and static content deploy once again.

Comment: @SukumarGorai I tried these things, and now I get 404s on all my static content ...

Comment: Did you run every commands like bin/magento setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, setup:static-content:deploy etc

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes, multiple times. The only thing they don't say is permissions are quite important. I had to give Apache write access to some extra directories and then it worked. The thing that really irked me though is the lack of decent error messages. There are a zillion logfiles, weird messages in the interface, but nowhere it says that it was a permission error. Magento might be the bees knees for e-commerce, it can still learn a lot on the config and installation front from for example Wordpress.